# Solr suggest component not working when using copy field

Tags: apache, search, solr, nosql

Even though I set the same parameters for the copy field and the individual fields, if set the suggest handler to use the copy field, I get nothing back. But if I set it to use one of the individual fields like "title", then it will give results back. Can you not use a copy field for suggest components? Or is there something wrong with my copy field?

[copy field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiD4v.png)

[field type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekCfp.png)

[copy field def](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJdUT.png)

[field def](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7ZFv.png)

[field def](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZhDh.png)

[request handler and search component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKMjk.png)

Answer (score 0):

You set multivalued to false. Set to true for multiple copyfield directives, as given by

```
Remember to configure your fields as multivalued="true" if they will ultimately get multiple values (either from a multivalued source or from multiple copyField directives).
```

in https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/copying-fields.html.

Comment: I had it at true, and it wasn't working then either, so I had set it to false to see if that worked. So both true and false aren't working. :/

Comment: did you check separately the contents in the field you copy to, e.g whether the field really contains values?

Comment: Yes, I did a query on the sc field to make sure it had stuff in it.